# Are all Debian .deb packages compatible with BunsenLabs Linux or only some?

Tags: linux, bunsenlabs

Can I install any Debian `.deb` packages in BunsenLabs Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [their website](https://www.bunsenlabs.org/):

> BunsenLabs Linux is a distribution offering a light-weight and easily customizable Openbox desktop. The project is a community continuation of CrunchBang Linux.
>
> The current release is Helium, derived from Debian 9 (Stretch).
>
> (...)
>
> The distribution consists of configuration and resource packages installed on top of Debian. There are no changes to the way the Debian base system is administrated.

So yes, you can install any Debian packages on it, provided that you define the correct repos.